# Usage of これでって時

Tags: reading-comprehension

> あんな時はにいちゃん就職してすくだったよね

His answer

> ばあちゃんと二人で年金生活苦しかったし。　やっとこれでって時だったな。。。やっと幸せにしてあげられると思ったんだけどな

Two　cousins are talking, the first one points out "Back, then you immediately got a job (after graduating)

While I do understand the cousin's answer "Living with a pension with grandma was hard. So I thought I could finally make her happy" I am not sure I understand "やっとこれでって時だったな"

What is this grammar trying to say? My understanding would be "I thought it was fine the time, with this", but I don't see why って?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't あ**の**時はにいちゃん就職してす**ぐ**だったよね. By the way, 就職してすぐ doesn't' mean the person immediately got a job. It means immediately after the person got a job.

Comment: You can think 「やっとこれで」って時, where 「」 is the feeling of the character at that time. That is, って is quoting the feeling.

Comment: It's def あん時 but you are right about すぐ。

Comment: You put あん**な**時... あん時 is a contracted form for あの時. They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

って時 is describing 時 with a quote, the quote says やっとこれで which translates to "finally. With this..." and expresses a feeling of relief that usually accompanies it. it refers to the time when he found a job but they were living on pension before. So "Finally. With this (job we don't have to suffer anymore)". And in the next sentence it adds more information on what he thought then, 「**やっと**幸せにしてあげられると思った」